# How to enforce a browser to load all the components of the page using HTML?

Tags: html

I made a page using HTML which have some .jpg files and some .swf files, when someone open it with a slow net connection, some of those files are not loaded by the browser, which must be loaded even if it takes hours to load. Is there any solution for this problem? Is there any code available for HTML or any other language (priorly HTML)?

Comment: Without viewing your current relevant code structure what wave you tried so far; or a link to the referred page, it's hard to provide any help!

Comment: I am sorry but I can't show you the page, but may page have some. swf files, as buttons, some of which browsers do not load due to which function of that button becomes unavailable. That's what my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something you can configure from the server side (and especially not from your HTML).

This is determined by a **timeout** setting on the user's browser. They'll have to change the setting themselves if they so desire.

Comment: Can't we even put any component verifier, if not possible with HTML, is it not possible with any other language?

Comment: No, this is a setting on your user's browser, one you don't have permissions to mess with.

Answer (score 0):

For images, you could easily use javascript to request all of your assets, and once all of them are loaded show the rest of the page. You could have it hidden by default using CSS and then have javascript make it visible once again upon loading.

Here's an example of doing this: http://jsfiddle.net/HdSSL/

Preloading flash embeds is another story, however. You could do it by manually wrapping each embed in a container swf and monitoring the loading state of the child movie, but that's quite complicated and could potentially break some flash movies.